# How to make a .sh file execute in the Terminal on Debian through the GUI?

Tags: debian, executable, raspbian

I want to make a .sh file run via the Raspbian GUI run by simply double clicking on it.

I already made the file executable via `chmod +x` run in the Terminal by simply double clicking on it.

Right now, it opens a dialog pop-up telling me:

> This text file 'myfile.sh' seems to be an executable script. What do you want to do with it?
>
> Execute, Execute in Terminal, Open, Cancel

Clicking on any of the first two choices is without any effect. It just closes the dialog window.

Otherwise I can just run the script fine in the Terminal, just by typing `./myfile.sh`

Any idea what else I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps then you should find out what the command is to open the terminal in your distribution, and create a shortcut or the equivalent that runs that command with your script as an arg.

Ex: `bash /Home/myuser/path/to/your/script.sh`
(This works for me.)

Answer (score 0):

What is most probably happening here is what has happened to me many times, where I try to run a script like this, and it opens for a few milliseconds, because it finished running the code and exited. Try adding this at the end of your script, and see if the window is there:

```
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
```

If not, then I am sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: Hi! Actually that's not it because my script is actually a prompt that asks the user for input. So there's a 'read' line in there somewhere... but thanks anyway!